# What‘s different between inode->i_rwsem and i_flctx?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, ext4, inode

When I trace the function graph when calling `write()`, I find that within function `ext4_file_write_iter()` it locks the `inode->i_rwsem` by calling `inode_lock(inode)` at the beginning. After that call `__generic_file_write_iter()` to write data to file. And unlock the `inode` in the end.

So is it the `inode->i_rwsem` used to protect concurrent write to the same file?

But I write a program that concurrently writes data to the same region of a file (`pwrite(fd,buf,SIZE,0)`) and the result shows that writes are not serialized. And I found it has to use `flock`/`fcntl` to serialize concurrent writes which works deponded on `inode->i_flctx`.

What I want to ask is that what's the purpose of the `inode->i_rwsem`.

What is different among `inode->i_rwsem`, `inode->i_flctx` and `inode->i_lock`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inode->i_rwsem` is used internally by the kernel to ensure that the kernel itself doesn't read or write from/to a file at the same time, to avoid any corruption or race conditions. It doesn't affect the userspace; you can still have the file opened for read/write by multiple processes at the same time. But if multiple processes try to read/write from/to the file simultaneously,  the kernel will actually do it serially behind the scenes.

In you case, if there are two processes that are trying to write to the same region with `pwrite(fd,buf,SIZE,0)`, without an internal locking mechanism such as what `i_rwsem` is used for, the kernel might start writing some of the data from the first process, and at the same time start writing the data from the second processes, without the write operation of the **first** process completed. It will impact the integrity of the entire filesystem, and might even lead to the kernel crashing due to [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

The internal locking in the kernel prevents those situations. The first write from the first process will complete, and only then the second write will be performed (and probably override the "write" from the first process, if they both write to exactly the same region in the file).

`inode->i_flctx`, as you've already found out, is controlled by `flock`/`fcntl` calls from userspace, when the process itself wants to limit the number of processes the can have the file open at the same time. For instance, one process can lock the file for writing, and if another one wants to lock the same file before the other one releases it, it will be denied or blocked.

Let's take this case of two processes that write to the same file, and perform different writes. Each process could override the data written by the other process. In order to avoid that in the **userspace**, the **application itself** could use `flock`/`fcntl` to prevent two processes opening the same file.

Here's another example:

- One process writes to a file, and a second process reads from the same file.
- The second process could read partial data because the first one hasn't completed the write.

In that case, to prevent this situation:

1. The first process will have to acquire a lock the file to prevent other processes from opening it until it finishes the write.
2. The second process will try acquire a lock to the same file, and will be blocked (or failed, depends on how it tried to lock the file) because it's already locked by another process.
3. The first process finishes the write, releases the lock (again,
   explicitly in **userspace** by calling one of the system calls
   mentioned)
4. Only then the second process could lock the file for reading.
5. While the second process is reading the file, other processes that
   will try to acquire lock for the file will again get blocked until:
6. The reading process finishes the reading.

So with `flock`/`fcntl` you can handle those cases **programmatically** in the application's source code, and the kernel uses `i_flctx` to know if a certain process acquired a lock to the file, and to prevent other process to acquire another lock until the first process released it.

`inode->i_lock`, just like `inode->i_rwsem`, is used only by the kernel to protect the kernel from race conditions when dealing with the inode's state in the kernel. `i_rwsem` is used to protect the writing, `i_lock` is used to protect changes in the inode state.

In other words, unless you're a kernel developer, you shouldn't worry about `inode->i_lock` or `inode->i_rwsem`, which are only parts of the kernel's implementation mechanism of a inode, and also about `inode->i_flctx` which is part of the kernel's internal implementation mechanism of file locking from userspace.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am writing a toy filesystem. But the i_rwsem and i_flctx still confuse me. As you mention "multiple processes try to read/write from/to the file simultaneously, the kernel will actually do it serially behind the scenes". The simultaneously read/write from/to the file has been serialized then why need i_flctx?

Comment: @user503990, In "serialized" I didn't mean that the writes will be written serially into the file; I mean that the **kernel** itself is not able to perform two write actions simultaneously to the same file. If there are multiple processes trying to write to the same file, the kernel will do one write, and when it finishes it will do a second write. Those two writes could override each others, but the kernel will still do those writes in two separate actions serially to avoid **race conditions**. So i_rwsem  is used only by the **kernel** to avoid concurrent write actions and race conditions.

Comment: @user503990, `i_flctx` is being used when a **user** calls `flock` / `fcntl` to lock the file. If you have multiple scripts and applications that could read or write to/from the same file, and you avoid that, the application could `lock` the file first (in userspace), and other applications that will try to lock the same file will not be able to do that until the first process will release it. When any process explicitly calls `flock` / `fcntl` to lock a specific file, it will be marked in `i_flctx`, so other processes will not be able to lock the file at the same time until it's released.

Comment: thank you so much. It seems I am misunderstanding the purpose of the i_rwsem. It is used to protect concurrently update to the inode structure. And making concurrently writes serially into a file seems like its side-effect.  Am I right?
It is the i_flctx designed to provide concurrency control to serialize read/write from/to a file. Am I right?

Comment: @user503990 No, it's not related to the inode structure. As I've said multiple times, it's to prevent **race conditions** and prevent possible filesystem integrity issue. If one kernel thread starts writing to a file, and then at the same time another kernel thread (or during context switch between the threads) will try to write to the same file before the previous operation ended. It will risk the integrity of the file system structure, or worse - the kernel might even crash. Read about race conditions. `i_rwsem` is there to **protect** the kernel to reaching hazardous situations.

Comment: @user503990, I've updated my answer and elaborated some more. Hope if clarifies your questions. If it's still not clear, you should probably read more about kernel development. There are some good books that explain the concepts of locking and filesystems. It seems to me you're lacking some basic knowledge in kernel development, and that's why you're confused.